# jQuery 3 + Ajax + PHP send mail form not sending mail

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-3

I've been trying to re-write a jQuery + PHP send mail form but despite trying 3 methods it's still throwing a 500 Internal Server Error. I'm rewriting because I'm migrating the site to jQuery 3 and working on improving performance and standards compliance with a codebase I've inherited.

I know 500 is a server error and the site is hosted on MS IIS, but the legacy code is working on the same server, so there must be something specific to my implementation.

Maybe you can see something I've missed?

- [Live page throwing the error](http://radiuscare.co.nz/waikato-bop/radius-althorp-draft.html)
- [Legacy page with working form](http://radiuscare.co.nz/waikato-bop/radius-althorp.html) (jQuery 2.2.4)

The below code mostly follows [this example on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5004276/8717667) but I've also tried following [this youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kcNQYLHeiYA) and [this tutorial](https://themehunt.com/blog/53-tutorial/162-how-to-create-an-ajax-contact-form-without-any-plugin) without success.

Hoping for an answer here after exhausting my other options. Thanks in advance!

**HTML (simplified)**

```
<form action="send_mail_facility2.php" id="facility-contact-form" method="post" autocomplete="on">
  <!-- MAIN FIELDS -->
  <input id="sendTo" name="sendTo" type="text" value="Facility One" style="display: none;">
  <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" required>
  <input id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" required>
  <input id="phone" name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone number">
  <textarea id="message" name="message" type="text" placeholder="Message"></textarea>

  <!-- ADDITIONAL FIELDS - separate js shows section when checkbox selected -->
  <input id="infopack-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="checkbox"><span class="information-pack">&nbsp;I would like to receive an information pack.</span>
  <div id="address-details">
    <input id="address" name="address" type="text" placeholder="Address">
    <input id="city" name="city" type="text" placeholder="City">
    <input id="postcode" name="postcode" type="text" placeholder="Postcode">
  </div>

  <!-- reCAPTCHA html & js -->

  <input id="facility-submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send request" disabled style="opacity: 0.3;"> <!-- disabled & inline style for captcha -->
  <p class="status" style="display: none" role="alert">Thanks, someone will be in contact with you regarding your enquiry soon.</p>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
  var request;
  $("#facility-contact-form").on("submit", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if (request) {
      request.abort();
    }
    var $form = $(this);
    var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");
    var serializeData = $form.serialize();
    $inputs.prop("disabled", true);
    request = $.ajax({
      url: "send_mail_facility2.php",
      type: "post",
      data: serializeData
    });
    request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
      console.log("Hooray, it worked!");
    });
    request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
      console.error("The following error occurred: "+
                   textStatus, errorThrown);
    });
    request.always(function () {
      $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
    });
  });
});
```

**PHP**

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

  // email headers
  $to       = $_POST["sendTo"];
  $subject  = "Custom subject line";
  $headers  = "From: NoReply &lt;noreply@noreply.com&gt;";

  // sender data
  $name     = $_POST["name"];
  $email    = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
  $phone    = trim($_POST["phone"]);
  $message  = trim($_POST["message"]);
  $address  = isset($_POST["address"]) ? trim($_POST["address"]) : null;
  $city     = isset($_POST["city"]) ? trim($_POST["city"]) : null;
  $postcode = isset($_POST["postcode"]) ? trim($_POST["postcode"]) : null;

  //define recipients
  $sendTo = $_POST["sendTo"];

  if($sendTo == 'Facility One') {
    $to = 'mytestemail@example.com';
  } elseif($sendTo == 'Facility Two') {
    $to = 'two@clientemail.com';
  } elseif($sendTo == 'Facility Three') {
    $to = 'three@clientemail.com';
  }

  if (isset($_POST['checkbox'])) {
    $infoPack = "Yes";
  } else {
    $infoPack = "No";
  }
  if (empty($_POST["address"])) {
    $address = "N/A";
  } else {
  }
  if (empty($_POST["city"])) {
    $city = "N/A";
  } else {
  }
  if (empty($_POST["postcode"])) {
    $postcode = "N/A";
  } else {
  }

  // email content
  $content = "Enquiry for facility: $sendTo\n\n";
  $content .= "Name: $name\n\n";
  $content .= "Email: $email\n\n";
  $content .= "Phone: $phone\n\n";
  $content .= "Message:\n$message\n\n";
  $content .= "Would user like to receive an information pack?: $infoPack\n\n";
  $content .= "Address: $address\n\n";
  $content .= "City: $city\n\n";
  $content .= "Postcode: $postcode\n\n\n";
  $content .= "Static footer message here\n\n";

  // Send the email
  $success = mail($to, $subject, $content, $headers);
  if ($success) {
    http_response_code(200);
    echo "Thanks, someone will be in contact with you regarding your enquiry soon.";
  } else {
    http_response_code(500);
    echo "Oops, something went wrong - we couldn't send your message.";
  }

} else {
    // Not a POST request, set a 403 (forbidden) response code.
    http_response_code(403);
    echo "Oops, something went wrong - we couldn't send your message.";
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: your throwing the error `http_response_code(500);`

Comment: @smith yep, sure. But that's because it's not working. If I remove that line, still no email sends, etc.

Comment: well ok, but i shouldn't have to read your code to get to that point, the 500 is not an issue as your the one generating it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP mail function doesn't complete sending of e-mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644436/php-mail-function-doesnt-complete-sending-of-e-mail)

Comment: dont use php's nail() its very basic use: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer turn on its debugging and it will tell you the problem.

Comment: Your script is already returning the errors (*what's causing it to fail*) - https://pastebin.com/pDAyBNs1

Comment: Thanks @Darren I think it's working now! Sorry I'm new to this... where did you pull these errors? They aren't showing up in my error_log

Comment: I simply followed the jQuery request through Chrome's network tab. When you submit your form, look at the requests to: `send_mail_facility2.php` and it'll spit out the errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Darren who pointed me to the error response.

The problem appears to have just been the `from` header syntax which I copied from step 3 of [this tutorial](https://themehunt.com/blog/53-tutorial/162-how-to-create-an-ajax-contact-form-without-any-plugin).

I changed:

```
$headers  = "From: NoReply &lt;noreply@noreply.com&gt;";
```

to:

```
$headers = "FROM: NoReply <noreply@noreply.com>";
```

I didn't get this from [the question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24644450/8717667) that was listed as a duplicate, as useful as that answer is.

For other PHP newbies, use Firefox/Chrome developer tools Network tab, run through submitting your form, filter for your php file and then look at the Response tab to see the full response with any errors.

Comment: Good work mate, it's always the "simple" things that get us haha!